# How to reduce the time to write pandas dataframes as table in Amazon Redshift

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, amazon-redshift

I am writing python pandas data frame in Amazon Redshift using this -

```
df.to_sql('table_name', redshiftEngine, index = False, if_exists = 'replace' )
```

Although my dataframes have couple of thousand rows and 50-100 columns only, its taking 15-20 minutes to write one table. I wonder if that is normal performance in redshift ? Is there any way to optimize this process and speed up writing the table ?

Answer (score 2):

A better approach is use `pandas` to store your dataframe as a CSV, upload it to S3 and use the `COPY` functionality to load into Redshift. This approach can easily handle even hundreds of millions of rows. In general, Redshift write performance is not great - it's meant for processing data loads that are dumped in by huge ETL operations (like `COPY`).

Comment: `single insert statement and commit`, millions of row with `copy` import, you will take almost same time, Adding to what @rvd said, you could even parallel, using `menifest` file option.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a better approach to upload data into Redshift is to upload file as a .csv file into S3 bucket, then read the file from there.

Firstly, save the file as a .csv file. If you are doing that in excel, then select 'CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)' to deal with special characters correctly.
Then run these codes (modify sections accordingly). This is for a two columns table; add more if you have a larger table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table.table;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table.table
(
    col1            VARCHAR(1024)   ENCODE lzo,
    col2            VARCHAR(1024)   ENCODE lzo
);


copy table.table
from 's3://address/address/address/file_name.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=#################;aws_secret_access_key=####################'
FORMAT CSV
DELIMITER ','
IGNOREHEADER 1
region 'region_name'
--ACCEPTINVCHARS
;
```